# update facebook graph API to v2.7

Tags: facebook, api, graph

I need to update Facebook graph API to use the latest one i.e. v2.7. In previous implementation I don't see any version number implemented in code. Could you please help me how do we implement latest version for facebook graph API.

Thank You
Harish Singh

Answer (score 0):

API Upgrade Tool
: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/api_versioning/

...or just add the version tag in your API calls/paths, which is explained in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me?access_token=xxx
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Actually I was looking for an example which I could find there. We are calling API like https://graph.facebook.com/<api URL>&access_token=<access token>  which doesn't include version lie v2.6 anywhere. So in such scenarios how could I update version.

Comment: That didn't work for me. As I told earlier that we don't use version number in API URL.

Comment: then use the upgrade tool...or create a new app, it will be an app with the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

For facebook version update, here is the latest guide I found (to facebook lib version 2.8): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

1. You need go to the facebook "API updated tool" (an online page), and upgrade the API version you facebook app use. Facebook will track whether you call need be updated using the newest API
2. May be you also need to update the sdk for your script: (for example for the python in ubuntu)

> sudo pip install -U facebook

The above cmd may not work because the pip repository not have a new version yet, then you need to download the source code of the new API in the git page, unzip the code, in the folder where you unzip the code, run the install cmd yourself :

> ```
> sudo python setup.py install
> ```

see latest facebook python API guide page https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk

Zhihong